# how to transfer amount from stripe to account in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using stripe payment gateway , i need to transfer amount from stripe account to bank account 
I read this document,
https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_create_card

i used this code for nodejs

```
var stripe = require("stripe")(
 "sk_**********************nUl"
);

stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
  "acct**************6Y",
  { external_account: "to**************52s" },
  function(err, card) {
    // asynchronously called
  }
);
```

I got this error from stripe ,but i used this same key for payment .

Error: The provided key 'sk_test_********************unUl' does not have the required permissions for this endpoint on account 'acct_19aqKGBABF9ppg6Y'. Having more permission would allow this request to continue.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if, for example, you're using an API key that has read-only access to a connected account. I would recommend writing into Stripe support so someone can take a look directly at your accounts and give specific advice!

https://support.stripe.com/email/login

Comment: hi , @hpar , i need to transfer the amount from stripe to bank account , i struggled with flow , stripe docs is not clear from me , if you know ,please reply me .